# The standard error of precision from the standard error of intermediate precision and repeatability of a analytical chemical method

Tags: standard-error, error, measurement-error, error-propagation, chemometrics

A validation report of an analytical method (to determine the assay of a product) is given and the goal is to try to determinate the overall uncertainty of it. I started with calculating the standard error of the precision of the method. The precision can be usually decomposed in three parts: the intermediate precision, the repeatability and the reproducibility. In this case, the reproducibility is not given.

Let us note $\sigma_P$, $\sigma_{ip}$ and $\sigma_r$ the standard error of the precision, the standard error of the intermediate precision and the standard error of the repeatability.
My thinking is, to determine $\sigma_P$, I can use the following relation:
$$
\sigma_P = \sqrt{\sigma_{ip}^2 + \sigma_r^2} \ \ (E1).
$$

However, I do not see the mathematical justification for that.

Furthermore, in the validation report, the repeatability is not given, is only accessible the intermediate repeatability which I do not really know what is it.

And a last point, we are in a phase 3 of a drug product development, in the validation report the precision of the phase IIb was calculated and it is around 0.7% but the intermediate precision of the current phase (phase 3) is around 0.7% too. They kept the result of phase IIb for the precision.

My questions are:

1. Is it correct to use equation $(E1)$ to link $\sigma_P$ to the other standard errors? If yes, why? Mathematically it would be similar to suppose that the repeatability $R$ and intermediate precision $IP$ are normally distributed with standard deviation $\sigma_r$ and $\sigma_{ip}$ respectively and that we have a relation of the form $P = R + IP$, where $P$ is the precision.

2.Can I take the intermediate repeatability as the repeatability of the process?

3.I find it a bit suspicious to have a standard error of the precision at the same level of the intermediate precision, shouldn't it be significantly higher (like at least 0.1%)?